# If the derivative of the natural logarithm $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, why isn't the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}=x$?

Tags: calculus

It might seem a little bit weird why I would think that, and I already know that $\frac{d}{dx}e^{ax}=ae^{ax}$. But I'm thinking that the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=ax$, which can be interpreted as saying that the slope at each value of $x$ is equal to $x$ itself and has the solution $x(t)=e^{at}$, so using the differential equation above shouldn't the derivative be $\frac{d}{dt}e^{at}=at$?
It would also make sense because the logarithm is sort of the inverse of an exponetial and the inverse of it's derivative which is$\frac{1}{x}$ is then $\frac{1}{x}^{-1}=x$.

Comment: You're using $^{-1}$ as both inverse notation and reciprocal notation.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation) on derivatives of inverse functions may be worth a read.

Answer (score 3):

If $y=e^x$ then $x=\ln y$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac1y$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{dx/dy}=y\ne x$.